# Сгруппировать подмассивы по совместным элементам

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть большой массив подмассивов. Каждый подмассив содержит элементы и в каждом подмассиве есть хотя бы один элемент, который дублируется еще в каком то подмассиве.

Например:

```
[
    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
    ['ddd', 'aaa'],
    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee'],
    ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn'],
    ['mmm', 'ooo'],

]
```

В данном случае элементы 'ddd' и 'eee' например нигде не дублируются, но другие элементы в тех же подмассивах например 'aaa' дублируются еще хотя бы в каком то одном подмассиве. Нужно сгруппировать подмассивы с одинаковыми элементами чтобы получить на выходе:

```
[
    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee'],
    ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo']
]
```

Comment: а если будет такой что и aaa и mmm ?

Comment: Нет, в том то и дело, что aaa и mmm нигде вместе в одном подмассиве не встречаются

Comment: Я так понял, на выходе должно быть всегда 2 подмассива: в 1-м только неуникальные элементы, во 2-м только уникальные. Правильно?

Comment: Подмассивов там немеряно, это я только для примера привел две группы

Comment: @stckvrw он не спрашивает про количество подмассивов он спросил : на выходе должно быть всегда 2 подмассива: в 1-м только неуникальные элементы, во 2-м только уникальные???

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов - там aaa общий в первом и mmm общий во втором

Comment: Что значит на выходе всегда должно быть два подмассива? На выходе должны быть подмассивы-"группы"

Comment: вы можете построить объект (словарь) - элемент: [список индексов подмассивов, где он есть], отобрать все длиннее одного. А дальше думайте, что с этим делать. Кроме aaa и mmm еще и bbb будет

Comment: что-то такое получится  {
  "aaa": [
    0,
    1,
    2
  ],
  "bbb": [
    0,
    2
  ],
  "ccc": [
    0,
    2
  ],   "mmm": [
    3,
    4
  ]}

Comment: А если будет такой массив: [["aaa","bbb"], ["bbb", "ccc"], ["ccc", "ddd"], [""ddd", "eee"], ["eee", "aaa"]], с ним что делать? Собирать в один массив?

Comment: неудачно простой пример : два с bbb, два с ddd :)

Comment: @splash58, если это на мой комментарий было сказано, то обратите внимание, что второй и третий подмассивы имеют общий элемент "ccc". Но для наглядности добавлю еще один подмассив.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов да, верно. Нужно собрать всех "друзей" по группам. Например если aaa где то "дружит" с bbb, а bbb где то "дружит" с eee, значит всех в одну группу. Но aaa нигде не дружит с mmm, хотя mmm где то дружит с nnn, значит mmm и nnn в отдельную группу.

Comment: @stckvrw да, Ваш пример я понял, просто пытался уточнить требования...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попытался сделать что-то типа такого.. Не уверен, что эффективно, но других идей пока нет...

1. Взял первый подмассив, положил его в первую группу итогового
   массива, удалил из исходного.
2. Взял первый элемент первой группы, проверил все подмассивы исходного массива.
3. Те, что содержат проверяемый элемент, добавил целиком в группу, удалив их из исходного массива.
4. Дойдя до конца исходного массива, перешел к следующему элементу группы и повторил шаг 3.
5. Проверив последний элемент группы, посмотрел - если в исходном массиве еще что-то осталось, то первый из оставшихся подмассивов положил в новую группу, и повторил для нее шаги 3-5.

Единственное - не учитываю возможность дублирования элементов в итоговых группах.

Answer (score 0):

Получил ответ на англоязычном SO:

```js
const data = [
  ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  ['ddd', 'aaa'],
  ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee'],
  ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn'],
  ['mmm', 'ooo']
]

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  const match = r.find(a => e.some(s => a.has(s)))
  if (!match) r.push(new Set(e));
  else e.forEach(el => match.add(el))
  return r
}, []).map(e => Array.from(e))

console.log(result)
```